# IConfigureOptions<T> with an AuthenticationBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I've used IConfigureOptions in the past and have a new project that I'm working on using OAuth introspection.

I tried to set up the options pattern with a class:

```
    public class
        ConfigureOAuth2IntrospectionOptions : IConfigureOptions<
            OAuth2IntrospectionOptions>
    {
        private readonly Settings settings;

        public ConfigureOAuth2IntrospectionOptions(IOptions<Settings> options)
        {
            settings = options.Value;
        }

        public void Configure(OAuth2IntrospectionOptions options)
        {
            options.IntrospectionEndpoint =
                $"{settings.IdentityServer.Authority}/connect/introspect";
            options.ClientId = ScopeNameConstants.MyClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = settings.IdentityServer.ClientSecret;
        }
    }
```

And in my startup.cs I have this code:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =
                            OAuth2IntrospectionDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultChallengeScheme =
                            OAuth2IntrospectionDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
                .AddOAuth2Introspection();
```

I add to DI Bindings:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OAuth2IntrospectionOptions>, ConfigureOAuth2IntrospectionOptions>();
```

However, the configure method is never called in my configuration class.

The AddOauth2Introspection method has a method with an Action parameter like this that I thought would automatically be used:

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddOAuth2Introspection(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, string authenticationScheme, Action<OAuth2IntrospectionOptions> configureOptions)
```

Is this possible to use by default? I want to use this pattern so that I can use constructor injection for my configuration object rather than referencing configuration directly in `Startup.cs`.

I might also have to do encryption/decryption which would need an injected class that I don't want to make available in the ConfigureServices method.

Edit:
Example Swashbuckle implementation from the Microsoft Docs:

Initial ticket:
https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/422

New example:
https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample/ConfigureSwaggerOptions.cs

Comment: I'm failing to understand what you want to achieve probably, but why you just don't register your class that contains your `Authority`, `MyClientId`, `ClientSecret` normally and then resolve it from the container and use it to set the properties for `AddAuthentication`?

Comment: I don't want to use Configure[Settings:IdentityServer:ClientId]. I'm trying to set up a new class to handle setting the Oauth options for introspection.

Here is an example of using it for swashbuckle:
https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/422



And the implementation here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample/ConfigureSwaggerOptions.cs

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://andrewlock.net/adding-validation-to-strongly-typed-configuration-objects-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: @johnluke.laue That won't work because the AddOauth2Introspection method that I'm calling is a static method that builds on top of an AuthenticationBuilder.

It's in a nuget package so I don't have the ability to inject dependencies directly into it.

Answer (score 1):

Try IConfigureNamedOptions because authentication schemes are named. You have to implement an extra Configure method that takes a name. You can still DI bind your class as IConfigureOptions